# Custom Sort using Excel without Custom List

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I want to be able to sort excel rows where data looks like

```
Column - 1                 Other Columns

701-GBL-1843-MLMK          blah
566-JJB-2785-MYJW
254-WYD-3220-NAND
884-GLE-2843-FRYA
```

And I want to be able to sort the data by the third parameter, so that im comparing by the numbers in the middle of the string, so that it will end up like

```
701-GBL-1843-MLMK
566-JJB-2785-MYJW
884-GLE-2843-FRYA
254-WYD-3220-NAND
```

Is there a way to do this, rather than making a custom list that will be 100000000000000 items long

Basically I want to want to know how to write code for excel where I can make a custom compare that will be like

pseudo:

```
mycompare(cell1, cell2):
    if(cell1's third param > cell2's third param):
        return GREATER
    if(cell1's third param < cell2's third param):
        return LESS
    return EQUAL

sort(myWorksheet, mycompare)
```

Needless to say, I do not know how to program or use VB. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a helper column.  In row 2 of that column (assuming that row 1 has headers) enter the formula

```
=MID(A2,9,4)
```

This will extract the “third parameter” from the value in the first column. 
Then sort on the helper column:

[image: sorting on helper column]

Answer (score 1):

The approach I would take is to generate an extra column of data.  Assuming the format of your values in column one are always fixed length as in your example, I would use,
`=MID(A2,9,4)` to extract the third element into a separate cell, so that you can then sort on that column.  My formula example picks out the 4 character starting at the 9th character position, which seems to work for the examples of data shown.

If you need a formula that extracts the 3rd element based on finding the 2nd and 3rd dashes and the number between them it can be done too, I just need to actually play with that one to find the shortest approach, but it can be done easily.

Answer (score 0):

I know you have an answer, but since you asked how to do it with VBa

```
Option Explicit

Sub Testing()

Start (False) ' large to small
Start (True) ' small to big

End Sub

Sub Start(fromSmallToBig As Boolean)

Dim myRow As Integer
myRow = 1

Do While (Range("A" & myRow).Value <> "")

    Dim currentValue As String
    currentValue = Range("A" & myRow).Value

    Dim nextValue As String
    nextValue = Range("A" & myRow + 1).Value

    If (nextValue = "") Then
    Exit Do
    End If

    Dim first() As String
    first = Split(currentValue, "-")

    Dim second() As String
    second = Split(nextValue, "-")


    If (fromSmallToBig) Then
        Call Sorting(first(2), second(2), myRow, nextValue, currentValue)
    Else
        Call Sorting(second(2), first(2), myRow, nextValue, currentValue)
    End If

    myRow = myRow + 1

Loop

End Sub

Sub Sorting(first As String, second As String, myRow As Integer, nextValue As String, currentValue As String)

      If first > second Then

        Dim rowOne() As Variant
        rowOne = Rows(myRow).Value

        Dim rowTwo() As Variant
        rowTwo = Rows(myRow + 1).Value

        Rows(myRow).Value = rowTwo
        Rows(myRow + 1).Value = rowOne

        myRow = 0 ' start all over again, not efficient but, simpler code

    End If

End Sub
```

This also means you don't need to have any extra columns just for sorting, although this may actually not be a good thing (Scott's answer does allow you to use the power of Excel, whereas my VBa answer is no bells and may be not very efficient with very large data)